# Python code-folding in emacs?

Tags: python, emacs, editor, folding

I have many classes and defs ...

I want to have `+` and `-` keys before `class` and `def` to collapse the class or open it ( toggle it ).

How i can do this?

Comment: Do you care about the functionality (code folding) or the +, - signs? Emacs is keyboard-based so it doesn't really make sense to use the mouse for toggling the +, -. Check [1085170](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085170/how-to-achieve-code-folding-effects-in-emacs)

Comment: no surly ... only i want see class is collapse and then open it and in other way

Comment: Good. See the link that I gave you; In the link there is a reference to the [Emacs folding mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FoldingMode) which might work for you.

Comment: Are you sure? Take a careful look in the python-related answer of [1085170](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085170/how-to-achieve-code-folding-effects-in-emacs/1085551#1085551) and the [Ruby](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FoldingMode#toc3) trick in the Emacs Wiki. Both ways look reasonable but you need to put some effort since python code is not wrapped using blocks like {}.

Comment: I haven't know that Emacs do code folding. This question is one of my favs!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Hideshow works out of the box and folds python code. It is built-in my version of emacs (24.3.1)

I have never needed more than these commands:

```
M-x hs-minor-mode
M-x hs-hide-all
M-x hs-show-all
```

To toggle use C-c @ C-c  which probably needs rebinding. You might also want to setup a hook in your .emacs file for hs-minor-mode to automatically be enabled when opening .py files.

I use it in combination the following to jump around.

```
M-x imenu <my_func_name>
```

Comment: This works great! But with a really large Python file (~5000 lines), things start lagging as I fold more classes. If I don't fold too many classes, it's okay. Specifically when I fold one class, ~1500 lines, it really slows down. I'm also using Elpy, which may be a factor.

Comment: 5000 lines python file!? Is there a good reason for such a large file?

Comment: @cammil Maybe not, but I don't think the text editor is the right place to enforce that norm. If nothing else, I should be able to use code folding to help deal with managing the 5000 line file when I go to refactor it.

Comment: How can I print the folded code? `ps-print-buffer` exports unfolded always.

Comment: for all the other command related to [hs-minor-mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hideshow.html)

Comment: Note that for Python, Hideshow can only fold entire functions. It can't do arbitrary scopes (like a loop or a conditional)

Answer (score 6):

You can get code folding (and more) with [CEDET](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/).  With CEDET, you should consider putting the following setting in your emacs configuration file:

```
(global-semantic-folding-mode t)
```

CEDET handles Python and other languages.

[Other ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085170/how-to-achieve-code-folding-effects-in-emacs) about how you can make emacs even more convenient when programming can be found on StackOverflow.

Comment: CEDET seems to be included with Emacs 24, but this function isn't available.  Has this changed in two years?