# Emacs: Is it possible to list all matching lines for a certain query string for marked files in dired?

Tags: search, emacs, dired

I found out M-x occur the other day.
([How to achieve code folding effects in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085170/how-to-achieve-code-folding-effects-in-emacs))

I wonder if I could list all matching lines in multiple files(or buffers) preferably *marked* in dired mode.

Answer (score 3):

```
M-x multi-occur

M-x multi-occur-in-matching-buffers
```

and also:

```
M-x multi-occur-in-this-mode

(defun get-buffers-matching-mode (mode)
  "Returns a list of buffers where their major-mode is equal to MODE"
  (let ((buffer-mode-matches '()))
   (dolist (buf (buffer-list))
     (with-current-buffer buf
       (if (eq mode major-mode)
           (add-to-list 'buffer-mode-matches buf))))
   buffer-mode-matches))

    (defun multi-occur-in-this-mode ()
      "Show all lines matching REGEXP in buffers with this major mode."
      (interactive)
      (multi-occur
       (get-buffers-matching-mode major-mode)
       (car (occur-read-primary-args))))
```

Answer (score 3):

### Files

This can be done using package [noccur](https://github.com/NicolasPetton/noccur.el) which can be installed from [MELPA](http://melpa.milkbox.net/#/getting-started).

It provides two functions:

- `noccur-dired` that will perform `multi-occur` on **dired marked files**
- `noccur-project` that will perform `multi-occur` on **all files in current project**. This is recursive.

From documentation a typical usage is: `M-x noccur-project RET foo RET`
The occur buffer's content can then be edited with occur-edit-mode (bound to e).  To save changes in all modified buffer and go back to occur-mode press `C-c C-c`.

### Buffers

This can be done using the built-in [ibuffer](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/IbufferMode). Mark buffers with `m` key, then key `O` to launch `ibuffer-do-occur` on **marked buffers**. I personally activate ibuffer using `(defalias 'list-buffers 'ibuffer)` in my `.emacs`.

You can also use the built-in `multi-occur-in-matching-buffers` that will perform `multi-occur` on **buffers matching a regexp**. Typical usage is `M-x multi-occur-in-matching-buffers RET ext$ RET regexp RET` where `ext$` is regexp for buffers already opened in Emacs, and `regexp` is what to match.

Answer (score 1):

You may try

```
(defun dired-do-multi-occur (regexp)
  "Run `multi-occur' with REGEXP on all marked files."
  (interactive (list (read-regexp "Regexp: ")))
  (multi-occur (mapcar 'find-file-noselect (dired-get-marked-files)) regexp))
```

Run it in a dired buffer with `M-x dired-do-multi-occur` or bind it to a key of your liking.

**Warning:** all marked files will be opened by emacs.

Answer (score 1):

In **Icicles**, use `M-s M-s m` (command `icicle-search-dired-marked-recursive`) to search the marked files in the current Dired buffer and in all marked subdirs, recursively.

Similarly, in your bookmark-list display the same key, `M-s M-s m`, searches the targets of all marked bookmarks.  And similarly for Ibuffer and Buffer Menu: `M-s M-s m` searches the marked buffers.

This is **Icicles** search, which is a different kind of incremental search (and on-demand replace).  You can confine searching within particular contexts (defined by a regexp).  The search hits are updated incrementally as you change your search pattern.  You can combine multiple search patterns, to refine your search progressively.  You can cycle through any set of search hits or access them directly.  You can change cycle orders --- you are not limited to buffer-occurrence order.

- http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview

Answer (score 1):

Let me improve on the answer of mk1 since I think it is the best one so far. This keeps the same history of previous searches of occur and allows for the optional argument for displaying more lines after or before the match (using C-u followed by a number before calling the function), just as in standard occur.

```
(defun dired-do-multi-occur (regexp &optional nlines)
  "Run `multi-occur' with REGEXP on all dired marked files."
  (interactive (occur-read-primary-args))
  (multi-occur (mapcar 'find-file-noselect (dired-get-marked-files)) regexp nlines))
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrt Dired:

Not sure whether you are asking (a) to regexp-search the files marked in Dired or (b) to mark files (in Dired) whose contents match a regexp. - or (c) something else.

- You can do the former (search marked files) using `A` (or `M-S a C-M-s` for incremental regexp search). And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18177868/729907) lets you search all files marked here and in marked subdirs (recursively).
- You can do the latter (mark the files whose contents match) using `%q` (`dired-mark-files-containing-regexp`).

Comment: If I've interpreted the question correctly, I think `diredp-do-grep` from your dired+ library may be a sensible answer.