# What is the emacs command to do full text search across all open buffers? like sublimetext's command+shift+f?

Tags: emacs, editor, sublimetext, emacs23

Title pretty much sums up the question. I am learning emacs and have all the basic commands mastered but I don't know how to achieve full text search yet

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but `M-x rgrep` can be quite useful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emacs: Is it possible to list all matching lines for a certain query string for marked files in dired?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661371/emacs-is-it-possible-to-list-all-matching-lines-for-a-certain-query-string-for)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `multi-occur-in-matching-buffers`.
You can give a blank for the regexp. Then the expression.

Answer (score 1):

There are several good ways to do what you ask. This is a ***duplicate question***.  See:

- [Emacs: Is it possible to list all matching lines for a certain query string for marked files in dired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661371/emacs-is-it-possible-to-list-all-matching-lines-for-a-certain-query-string-for/)
- [Sublime Text 2's "Goto Anything" (or instant search) for Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726601/sublime-text-2s-goto-anything-or-instant-search-for-emacs)